# React Native - TypeError: _firebase.default.auth is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I have a React Native App and have the following function:

```
import firebase from './firebase'

export function MainNavigator() {
  const [token, setToken] = useAtom(tokenAtom);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onIdTokenChanged(async (user) => {
      setToken(user ? await user.getIdToken() : null);
    });
  }, []);
  .....
  .... more code
```

This above code worked in Expo, but I have a new react native project (not built using expo) and this is failing:

I have the following in my `package.json` file:

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^13.0.1",
"@react-native-firebase/functions": "^13.0.1",
"firebase": "^9.5.0",
```

And my `firebase.js` file is like so (root directory)

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "Secret stuff",
    authDomain: "Secret stuff",
    databaseURL: "Secret stuff",
    projectId: "Secret stuff",
    storageBucket: "Secret stuff",
    messagingSenderId: "Secret stuff",
    appId: "Secret stuff",
    measurementId: "Secret stuff"
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase;
```

Im getting the following error:

> TypeError: _firebase.default.auth is not a function. (In
> '_firebase.default.auth()', '_firebase.default.auth' is undefined)

Comment: My guess is you were using the v8 API in your old project and now you're using v9. Check the documentation for differences (or revert to v8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the code you show imports the Firebase Authentication SDK. So when you then try to use `firebase.auth()` it correctly indicates that it can't find that SDK.

I'm guessing you want to import the Auth SDK too with something like:

```
import "firebase/auth";
```

I'd also recommend checking out the documentation on [upgrading to the v9 or v9/compat SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat).

Answer (score 1):

// v9 compat packages are API compatible with v8 code

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

[docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade)